# How can I extract this image link or attribute?

Tags: jsoup, picasso

**I'm having issue extracting images from website having images in brackets such as the one below**

`<a href="https://www.nigerianeye.com/2021/04/imo-attacks-ohanaeze-leadership-visits.html" class="lazyloaded" style="background: url(&quot;https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-F6KAyMdrt5g/YHHVrsEqEwI/AAAAAAAAj4A/CiZPHVyoX0cDc6Ij5mVL1sr_vonHjxMagCLcBGAsYHQ/w200-h200-p-k-no-nu/DE0B5706-931D-416C-99A0-EAB72E4F18E4.png&quot;) center center / cover no-repeat; display: block;"></a>`

or check the screenshot

[image]

help me get it complete in something like this

```
String imgUrl = data.select("a")
         .eq(i)
         .attr("");
```

Comment: 1. Don't post links to images. 2. Add your code, the input, the desired output and the errors you get.

Comment: I've done it... can you help me now